# Find limits of triple integration of a figure of cone topped with a sphere

Tags: multiple-integral

[image: CLICK HERE TO VIEW THE IMAGE OF THE FIGURE]

In the above figure, how do I find out the limits of integration when no equation of any sort is given? 
Please feel free to let me know if you want more pictures of the figure because it is rotatable. 
TIA :)

Comment: Here is one reason that changes of coordinates are a thing. In spherical coordinates this problem is trivial, having the bounds $0\leq r\leq 5, 0\leq \theta\leq360^\circ,0\leq\varphi\leq 45^\circ$. As for the Cartesian bounds, you have to make the equations from the description and picture.

Comment: @Arthur but this problems require limits for x, y and z. Is there any way I can do this without spherical coordinates>

Comment: I know it requires $x,y,z$ bounds. That's why I made it a comment, not an answer. Well, you should be able to get started, at least. $A$ and $B$ are easy, as they are just numbers. What numbers? Alternatively, the cone is $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and the sphere is $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$, so there are your equations.